# Why is it discouraged to access static members indirectly?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why is it discouraged to access static members indirectly? In Eclipse, you can en-/disable this warning under Preferences > Java > Compiler > Error/Warnings > "Indirect access to static member".

Example when "Indirect access to static member" is configured to cause a warning:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);       // causes warning    
label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);    // is ok
```

Comment: It would be cool to have a minimal self-contained example for people like me that didn't know that JLabel extends Component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to what was said by Marko Topolnik, there is the fact that if the `JLabel` was to have a static member by the same name in the future, the mere recompilation of the `JLabel.java` would not make the calling code aware of the *constant* existing in that module. Instead until recompilation of the code, it would still happily use the `Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT` despite the source code stating contrarily.

The latter reference is sure to refer to the static member of `Component` by the name `CENTER_ALIGNMENT`, whereas the former would refer to the member in either `Component` or in any subclass up to `JLabel` if the name is redefined in any of them later on.

In case of using a static function or member variable, if a later version of the subclass also declares an overridden one, the meaning of the indirect access would change even without recompilation. All of this might be a bit hypothetical, but good to consider anyway.

Comment: So the value of the constant is actually compiled into the bytecode?

Comment: +1 And actually, since we're talking `float` constants here, it wouldn't even reference the class; its compile-time value would be hardcoded in the referencing class.

Answer (score 19):

Accessing a member of the `Component` class through `JLabel` gives a false impression that this member is specific to `JLabel`, where in fact it is `Component`'s member and  just happens to be inherited by all its subclasses. Nothig is lost by accessing it through the declaring class, and there is definitely something won in clarity.

Comment: I always thought i made myself independt from refactorings in the class hierarchy. You lose the possibility of overriding the value in the subclass.

Comment: You cannot override class members. You can *hide* them, though, which would be an undisputed bad practice. Note that the API in question clearly states that the method you are calling accepts the constants as defined in the `Component` class.

Comment: Even if you could override them it would still be a bad idea to reference idirectly. Hypothatically speaking, if you want the value from `Component` as access it via `JLabel` and some other developer suddenly overrides it in `JLabel`, you would not get the value you intended to. Even worse this might happen without you noticing.